# Getting data from iRODS server from snakemake

Tags: snakemake

I am trying to download a file from an iRODS server using snakemake.

I have followed the instructions [here](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/remote_files.html).

I am working on a GNU/Linux computer cluster.

I have got this at the top of my Snakefile:

```
from snakemake.remote.iRODS import RemoteProvider

irods = RemoteProvider(irods_env_file='/nfs/users/nfs_c/username/.irods/irods_environment.json',
                       timezone="Europe/London") # all parameters are optional
```

This code runs smoothly in the Python interpreter without causing an error.

I then have this rule:

```
rule iget:
    input:
        irodsBam = irods.remote('/seq/path/to/my/file.bam')
    output:
        lustreBam = 'new/file/location/on/lustre.bam'
    conda:
        'envs/iget.yaml'
    shell:
        'iget -K -f {input.irodsBam} {output.lutreBam}'
```

In the yaml file, I've got this:

```
channels:
  - bioconda
  - r
dependencies:
  - boto
  - moto
  - filechunkio
  - pysftp
  - dropbox
  - requests
  - ftputil
  - XRootD
  - biopython
```

And I ran snakemake with:

```
snakemake --use-conda new/file/location/on/lustre.bam
```

I have got an error:

```
Building DAG of jobs...
MissingInputException in line 146 of /lustre/projects/main/Snakefile:
Missing input files for rule igetPacbio:
/seq/path/to/my/file.bam
```

However, I checked with ils and my BAM file is on iRODS at the specified location.

Can anyone help me, please?

### Update 13th November 2018

I have also tried this rule:

```
rule iget:
    input:
        irodsBam = irods.remote('/seq/path/to/my/file.bam')
    output:
        'new/file/location/on/lustre.bam'
    conda:
        'envs/iget.yaml'
    shell:
        r"""
        touch {output}
        """
```

but the error is the same:

```
MissingInputException
```

### Update 24th November 2018

```
ils /seq/pacbio/r54097_20170511_114349/1_A01/
```

gives

```
/seq/pacbio/r54097_20170511_114349/1_A01:
  m54097_170511_115331.adapters.fasta
  m54097_170511_115331.scraps.bam
  m54097_170511_115331.scraps.bam.pbi
  m54097_170511_115331.sts.xml
  m54097_170511_115331.subreads.bam
  m54097_170511_115331.subreads.bam.pbi
  m54097_170511_115331.subreadset.xml
```

And removing the '/' in '/seq/path/to/my/file.bam' does not change the error. It still is a MissingInputException.

Comment: I have never used the irods backend myself, but I think the path should not have a leading slash.

Comment: You mean this path '/seq/path/to/my/file.bam'? I've tried without the '/' but it still gives a MissingInputException.

Comment: In that case, it is probably best to file an issue. I will try to connect you with the author of the irods remote provider.

Comment: Thanks. An issue where? Is there a Github repository of snakemake or the irods remote provider?